# How to build blender as shared libraries for Python2?

Tags: python, compile

I am trying to embed Blender as a backend (headless mode, no gui) into another program, I currently know how to build Blender as a python module, but Blender uses Python3, and my target program uses Python2 and C++, so I wonder if there is a way to build Blender as a module for Python2 (But I see that there are already some answers saying no), or to build Blender into some static libraries and header files, just like a Blender SDK? Can someone give some advice?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about [4. Developing Blender](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6)

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to compile Blender for python2, however it will likely be a good idea to convert your target to Python3 (Python2 is becoming obsolete quite quickly and most maintained libraries fully support py3 now). If it's impossible you might want to consider running a py3 micro-service with Blender as a compiled library, and have it communicate with your main py2 service via some standard protocol.